# how to hundle a database if we changed its structure using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring Boot, I ran into this issue yesterday and couldn't find any solution so you are my last chance,
I created this entity called data4D.java and its JpaRepository data4dJpaRepository :

```
@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Data4D {
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private Double dim1;
private Double dim2;
private Double dim3;
private Double dim4;

public Data4D(Double dim1,Double dim2,Double dim3,Double dim4) {
    this.dim1 = dim1;
    this.dim2 = dim2;
    this.dim3 = dim3;
    this.dim4 = dim4;

 }
}
```

Data4dRepository.java :

```
public interface Data4dRepository extends JpaRepository<Data4D, Long>{

}
```

but what if we have a table with +50 dims it is not healthy to add all the 50 dims to the POJO class.
and as 2nd scenario if we point to another database which has a different structure with a different column names, is it necessary to add entity and repeat all the procedures from scratch or there is a generic way to handle all scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. +50,you can use a list of dims

```
List<Double> dims = new ArrayList<>();
```

2. diff in schema, you can use liquibase for data migration
   https://docs.liquibase.com/home.html

this is a good tutorial to integrate liquibase with spring boot
https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app